# Why is the view not refreshed? (.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am learning .Net MVC. I have a page where I show productlines. I want to filter the productlines by their suppliers via a dropdownlist.

My controller:

```
public class ProductlineController : Controller
{
    SupplierRepository sr = new SupplierRepository();
    ProductlineRepository pr = new ProductlineRepository();

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        SupplierModel sm = new SupplierModel();

        List<Supplier> suppliers = sr.GetAll();

        sm.Suppliers = (from s in suppliers select new SelectListItem {
        Text = s.Name,
        Value = s.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        sm.Productlines = pr.GetAll();

        return View("List", sm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SupplierDropUsed(int id)
    {
        SupplierModel sm = new SupplierModel();

        List<Supplier> suppliers = sr.GetAll();

        sm.Suppliers = (from s in suppliers
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = s.Name,
                            Value = s.Id.ToString()
                        }).ToList();

        Supplier supplier = sr.GetById(id);
        sm.Productlines = supplier.Productlines.ToList();

        return View("List", sm);
    }
}
```

The default action shows all productlines. SupplierDropUsed is called when dropdownlist is changed.

The view:

```
@model RyfMvcTestApplication1.Models.SupplierModel
```

@{
    Layout = null;
}

List

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function supplierDropChanged() {

        $.post("Productline/SupplierDropUsed", { id: $('#SupplierDrop').val() });
    }

</script>

<div><strong>Filter by supplier</strong></div>
<br />

<div>

@Html.DropDownList("SupplierDrop", Model.Suppliers, "Select supplier", new { onChange = "supplierDropChanged()" })

</div>
<br />
<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px; text-align:left">Id</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Supplier</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Productlines) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.Name)
        </td>            
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I select a supplier, the javascript and controller action are executed (I checked in debug mode). I also get the correct supplier id. But the view is never refreshed. I still see the list with all productlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a post via the jquery post method which submits the request and that is why your debug action is called but that result that is returned from the post call is never used to update your UI.

Comment: Isn't that just describing the problem?